# Installing superset on docker: /bin/sh -c /frontend-mem-nag.sh & cc /app/superset-frontend && npm ci' return a non-zero code:127

Tags: docker, apache-superset

When I am installing superset on docker with the command docker-compose up.
It reaches state 13/37 and show following error.

Step 13/37 : RUN /frontend-mem-nag.sh         && cd /app/superset-frontend         && npm ci
---> Running in f7b92bd8222e
: No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'superset' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /frontend-mem-nag.sh
&& npm ci' returned a non-zero code: 127

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You might have resolved this, but I struggled with the same problem today so maybe someone else needs the answer.
If you are building the superset docker image on Windows and the target containers/VM are Linux based you will get the same error:

> /bin/sh -c /frontend-mem-nag.sh & cc /app/superset-frontend && npm ci' return a non-zero code:127

The problem appears in the .sh script because when you do git checkout/clone it automatically changes the line ending of the file to CRLF and docker tries to execute with the same line endings.

Solution:

> change the line endings to LF (use notepad++) and run the build command again.

source: [thread for different project with similar problem](https://github.com/postlight/headless-wp-starter/issues/171)

Comment: Thanks This is the correct answer, at least in my case and in my opinion it should be set as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. in my case is not on docker. I have changed the  files and then it work.